# Shared memory and streams when launching kernel

Tags: c, cuda, gpu, gpu-shared-memory

I'm new to CUDA and working on a personal project. I know that, if you want to specify the amount of shared memory at launch:

```
kernel<<<grid_size,block_size,shared_mem_size>>>(parameters);
```

On the other hand, if I want to put a kernel into a stream:

```
kernel<<<grid_size,block_size,0,stream_being_used>>>(parameters);
```

I don't understand why the third parameter is 0 in the case of stream? (I'm getting it from chapter 10 in "CUDA by examples" by Sanders and Kandrot).

If I want to specify the shared memory at launch AND put it into a stream, how do I do that correctly? In other words, what should the parameters in between `<<<...>>>` look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only reason that 0 is there is because in that particular example, no *dynamic* shared memory is required.

[Shared memory](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#shared) can be allocated either statically (without using `extern` in which case the size is explicitly stated in the declaration) or dynamically(using `extern`, and the size shows up as the 3rd parameter in the kernel launch configuration).

The kernel launch configuration parameters `<<<...>>>` always show up in the same order:

1. the grid dimensions
2. the threadblock dimensions
3. the size of dynamically allocated shared memory (in *bytes*)
4. the stream to launch the kernel in

1 and 2 are mandatory, 3 and 4 are optional.  But if you need to specify parameter 4 (the stream) *you must supply* parameter 3, even if it is zero.

so the correct sequence is:

```
kernel_name<<<grid_dim, threadblock_dim, dynamic_shared_memory_size, stream>>>(...);
```

You can read more about it in the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#execution-configuration)

Comment: And just to make it painfully clear, the third parameter will still remain 0 if you have statically allocated shared memory. i.e. something like

__ shared __ int array[10];